# SSRS - Recovering from a server crash

Tags: reporting-services

Our SSRS server crashed, so we have installed a new server with SSRS. We have backups of the ReportServer database, but that is all.

We imported the database backups, but I see that only the catalogue of reports is there, but not the actual report definitions. Also, on the reports server home page, there are no sub-folders, or report icons.

Can anyone suggest how to proceed? Do we scrap the existing ReportServer database, and start again? Or is there a way to use the existing database?

(According to our IT team, the data on the old server is fine, but we're waiting for another hardware component till we can use it again.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the existing database and perform a migration from the old server to the new server.  All your folders and report definitions should be intact as they are stored within the ReportDB.  The migration process is pretty well [documented on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156421.aspx) and I have performed it on numerous occasions.

Comment: Our IT is currently looking at that page. BTW, I didn't see the report definitions in the database because they're stored as a BLOB. But I found another answer here that explains how to get the report definitions from the catalogue table.